# Strange url in crawl of com_users

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, url

While trying to move site to 3.6.2
I was prehand crawling in url through Xenu efore making it live

However - found some strange url been crawled by xenu - almost more than 300 url like this

```
http://localhost/testsite/index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=L215Y2FydGVzdGZpbmFsL2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX2Vhc3libG9nJmFtcDt2aWV3PWVudHJ5JmFtcDtpZD0yNTgmYW1wO0l0ZW1pZD05MQ==&Itemid=9

http://localhost/testsite/index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=L215Y2FydGVzdGZpbmFsL2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX2Vhc3libG9nJmFtcDt2aWV3PWVudHJ5JmFtcDtpZD0yNjYmYW1wO0l0ZW1pZD05MQ==&Itemid=9

http://localhost/testsite/index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=L215Y2FydGVzdGZpbmFsL2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX2Vhc3libG9nJmFtcDt2aWV3PWVudHJ5JmFtcDtpZD0yNjcmYW1wO0l0ZW1pZD05MQ==&Itemid=9

http://localhost/testsite/index.php?option=com_users&view=login&return=L215Y2FydGVzdGZpbmFsL2luZGV4LnBocD9vcHRpb249Y29tX2Vhc3libG9nJmFtcDt2aWV3PWVudHJ5JmFtcDtpZD0yNDAmYW1wO0l0ZW1pZD05MQ==&Itemid=9
```

Can any one suggest -

1 what are these url generated by com_users

2 Is there any security flaw

3 How to mark them no index

Answer (score 1):

The return part is telling Joomla which page it should redirect to on success. It is not a security flaw.

In order to prevent Google from indexing this, then, you will need to override the login view and then use `setMetaData` to set the `robots` meta tag to `noindex, nofollow`. Note that Google may take an awful amount of time to de-index those pages, so be patient.